# Why is it not possible to change display name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Sorry if this question is misplaced, but I could not find the bug reporting functionality.

I'm trying to change my display name, but I'm getting this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Jul 23 at 17:33

Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: If you need your name changed more frequently than once every 30 days just email the address at the bottom of every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much intentional.  The error message should make that clear. (:

For background on why this is the case, [please read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29966/140548)

(And yes, here is the correct place for a post like this)

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything.